# Saving .maf file as a table

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to save a .maf file as a table, but I always get the error below:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("MAF", package = "maftools")’ to a data.frame
```

This is the code I am using:

```
library(maftools)

laml.maf <- "/Users/PC/mc3.v0.2.8.PUBLIC.maf"
laml = read.maf(maf = laml.maf)

write.table(laml, file="/Users/PC/tp53atm.txt")
```

I understand that the .maf file has several fields, but I am not sure how to isolate them to save as a table. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that the `write.table` function doesn't know how to deal with an object of class `MAF`.

However, you can access the underlying data like this:

```
write.table(laml@data, file="/Users/PC/tp53atm.txt")
```

But note that this way you will only export the raw data, whereas the `MAF` object contains various other meta data:

```
> slotNames(laml)
[1] "data"                           "variants.per.sample"            "variant.type.summary"           "variant.classification.summary"
[5] "gene.summary"                   "summary"                       
 "maf.silent"                     "clinical.data"                 
>
```